# Django-import-export change/remove records absent in uploaded file against db

Tags: django, django-import-export

I'm using [Django-import-export](http://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#creating-import-export-resource) module in my admin panel. I import .csv file extracted from our ERM system which updates records in Django myapp database. Everything works like a charm, except that when some records are removed from ERM and are not present in .csv datadump, no updates will be done in the Django database since records do not exist.

I want to write a clause when importing .csv file, change or delete (preferably change record name to "deleted") all records not present in mentioned .csv file. Records are identified by "number" column which is a primary key in the database.

Closest solution I could find was to add "delete" column and set "1" in uploaded file, however that does not help since those records don't exist in the first place.

Here's how my admin.py looks like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Supplier, SiteServices
from import_export import resources, widgets, fields
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin


# Register your models here.
class SupplierResource(resources.ModelResource):
    delete = fields.Field(widget=widgets.BooleanWidget())

    def for_delete(self, row, instance):
        return self.fields['delete'].clean(row)

    class Meta:
        model = Supplier
        import_id_fields = ['number']


class SupplierAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    resource_class = SupplierResource

admin.site.register(Supplier, SupplierAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1):

Override `after_import_instance` and save all imported ids in some variable, lets call it `imported_ids`. Override `after_import` and update Suppliers that are not in `imported_ids`.

See all hooks in documentation:

https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_resources.html#import_export.resources.Resource.after_import_row

Comment: Hi. Sorry for late reply, but only now was able to sit on the project. Thanks for the suggestion and I'm sure it works, but I'm too dumb to figure it out yet, so I will need to do trial and error until I have it. Do you change the resource file itself? If you have a practical example of something similar, it would greatly help me to reverse engineer.

Comment: I have added `def after_import_instance(self, instance, new, **kwargs):
        imported_ids = self.fields['number'].get_value(instance)
        print(imported_ids)` in my `admin.py`. It seem to print `imported_ids`. Not sure if that's the right way to go about it. Now I'm struggling to figure out how to update suppliers not in `imported_ids` with

Comment: something like `Supplier.objects.exclude(pk__in=imported_ids).update(delete=1)`

Comment: BTW, imported_ids would better be an instance variable of `SupplierResource` and code to update can go in resource instead admin class.

Comment: I have a 'after_import_instance' function inside SupplierResource class. I try to add your proposed solution inside function but I get "int is object not iterable" error. If I use it outside function, under class, I can't pass imported_ids values. I also can't call function because it needs 3 arguments. Here is screenshot http://imgur.com/a/A7Aa8 to show the issue

Comment: I have implemented it but after import function is called 2 times.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a worked out example that I implemented for this. This is the same approach as bmihelac suggests.

Create your own ModelResource, which handles the saving of instances that where in the import file, as well as a method to take care of the deletion of all other rows.

```
import import_export
class MyModelResource(import_export.resources.ModelResource):

    def after_import_instance(self, instance, new, **kwarg):
        """ For each row in the import file, add the pk to the list """
        self.imported_rows_pks.append(instance.pk)

    def after_import(self, dataset, result, using_transactions, dry_run, **kwargs):
        """  delete all rows not in the import data set. Then call the same method in the parent to still sequence the DB """
        self.Meta.model.objects.exclude(pk__in=self.imported_rows_pks).delete()
        import_export.resources.ModelResource.after_import(self, dataset, result, using_transactions, dry_run, **kwargs)
```

Instead of deleting, you can also say something like:

```
self.Meta.model.objects.exclude(pk__in=self.imported_rows_pks).update(deleted=True)
```

Then, create an import export Resource as you would do normally, except, you base it on the extended MyModelResource:

```
class SupplierResource(MyModelResource):
    imported_rows_pks = []

    class Meta:
        model = Supplier
        import_id_fields = ['number']
```

Comment: Hi @Paul in 't Hout  The after_import function is called 2 times, it may possibly due to confirm import action.